# Should I use the Data Persistence API or flat files to record GPS data on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I'm building a GPS recorder app for the iPhone, and I was wondering if anyone could say why I might use the data persistence API, instead of writing data to flat files?

Answer (score 1):

From my expirience using core data is more organized and a better expirence than using files.